# jQuery won't execute on page but does in JSFiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsfiddle

I made a jQuery code. it runs perfectly fine on JSFiddle, but won't work on my page.
I checked other questions and solutions, but none helped me so I'm asking again.

Here's the code:

HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Tic Tac Toe</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <h1>Tic Tac Toe</h1>
    <hr/>
    <p>Click play to start playing!</p>
    <div id="buttonPlay">Play!</div>
    <div id="can">
            <canvas id="s1" class="square"></canvas>
            <canvas id="s2" class="square"></canvas>
            <canvas id="s3" class="square"></canvas>
            <br/>
            <canvas id="s4" class="square"></canvas>
            <canvas id="s5" class="square"></canvas>
            <canvas id="s6" class="square"></canvas>
            <br/>
            <canvas id="s7" class="square"></canvas>
            <canvas id="s8" class="square"></canvas>
            <canvas id="s9" class="square"></canvas>
        <h3>Wins: </h3>
        <br/>
        <h3>Loses: </h3>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {

}
h1 {
    text-align: center;
}
p {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 24px;
    display: block;
}
#buttonPlay {
    width: 90px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: lime;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 32px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #888;
    display: block;
    margin-left: 47%; 
}
    #buttonPlay:hover {
        background-color: lightblue;
    }   
    #buttonPlay:active {
        background-color: lightblue;
        width: 85px;
        height: 45px;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px;
    }
#can {
    display: none;
    margin-left: 44%;
    margin-top: 100px;
}
.square {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    font-size: 25px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#buttonPlay').click(function() {
        $("p").css("background-color","yellow");
    });
});
```

As you see it's wip, but I had to stop because the jQuery didn't function.

Please help me out here.

**Problem solved!  Thanks you for the answers ^^**

Comment: Please, open your console next time... ;)

Comment: The console is a very helpful tool for web developers who use JavaScript!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are including jQuery AFTER your script... Your script doesn't have access to `$` yet. Change :

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

Comment: For some reason it's still not working. Tried and changed it to the code you sent, yet nothing special happened.

Comment: @user3235621 Then open your console, check if jQuery and you script is loaded. Add the protocol in case your firewall/server setting are too restrictive.

Comment: Haha never mind, you helped me out. seems like I had to add http:  before the //ajax.googleapis...

And had to change their positions ^^''  Thank you very much!

Comment: @user3235621 Yeah, this problem never occur when using the cdn jquery offer : `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

you have to include jQuery library before other script files that uses jQuery.Otherwise it will not able to access jQuery methods.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Putting http: before src=" might work

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

When working locally, use `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js`, not `//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js`, because locally the "protocol" is file://, not http://.